# Is there an analytical solution to Gaussian integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(x+a)^2+b} dx$?

Tags: definite-integrals, normal-distribution, error-function

I wonder if there is an analytical solution to

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(x+a)^2+b}  dx,$$

where $a, b>0$.

I know, of course, that the antiderivative of the fraction is a version of $\arctan$, and thus tried partial integration, but unfortunately this won't help. (I plugged it into Wolfram Alpha but it exceeded the computation time...)
I very much appreciate your effort!

EDIT: Maybe it is appropriate to rephrase the question a bit: I am searching for a closed-form or analytically tractable solution for the expected value of $\frac{1}{aX^2+b}$ where $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$ and $a,b>0$.

Comment: The integral does not converge for general $a,b>0!$ Take a look at Wolfram Alpha for $a=2, b=1$, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{(x+1)^2}  dx$.

Comment: Thank you. Let me specify: The denominator should better read $(x+a)^2+b$ for $a,b>0$.

Comment: Perhaps you can look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#Example_.28II.29_.E2.80.93_Cauchy_distribution

Comment: @johannesvalks: I tried to use the residue theorem (by integrating along the upper half-circle around 0 with radius $K$ while $K$ so big that the residue $i \sqrt{b} - a$ is inside the circle). Unfortunately, there seems to be no appropriate upper bound to the integrand such that the integral over the half-circle vanishes if $K$ approaches infinity. To see this, let $z=u+iv$. Then $e^{-z^2}=e^{v^2-u^2} e^{-2uv i}$. With $e^{v^2-u^2}=e^{K^2-2u^2}$ and $|e^{-2uv i}|=1$, it follows that $|e^{-z^2}|=e^{K^2}e^{-2u^2}$. Therefore, the integrand is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder if there is an **analytical** solution to $~\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{(x+a)^2+b}dx,~$ where $a, b>0$.

Depends what you mean by that. If you are willing to accept [imaginary error functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) as being “analytical”, then the answer is yes. Alternatively, one might try and expand $\dfrac1{(x+a)^2+b}$ into a [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), and then reverse the order of summation and integration in order to rewrite the integral in terms of [hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), but I'm afraid this might not work unless $b=a^2$.

Comment: I tried a bit but I do not get the derivation. How can I show it in terms of erfi? (I have actually hoped for some kind of closed-form [or at least real-valued] solution since this is part of a pricing formula in a simple financial market.)

Comment: @Dumdi44: Break up the quadratic denominator into partial fractions, then use the fact that $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x+z}dx = e^{-z^2}\bigg[\pi\text{erfi}(z)-\ln\bigg(-\frac1z\bigg)+\ln\frac1z\bigg]$. In this case, $z_{1,2}=-a\pm i\sqrt b$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I am still not able to derive the above fact. After dividing the original denominator into partial fractions, I applied the residue theorem as well as some trial-and-error partial integration. Both approaches weren't successful. Additionally, isn't it right that $-\ln\left(-\frac{1}{z}\right)+\ln\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=-\pi i$ if I use the principal value?

Comment: First let $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2} dx}{x+z}=e^{-z^2} \int_{\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-y^2+2yz}dy}{y}$$ via substitution. Then differentiate $I(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-y^2+2yz}dy}{y}$ under the integral to arrive at $$I'(z)=2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-y^2+2yz} dy=2\sqrt{\pi} e^{z^2}.$$ It must then hold that $$I(z)=2\sqrt{\pi} \int_0^z e^{x^2} dx+C=\pi \text{erfi(z)}+C.$$ Because $\text{erfi}(0)=0$ and the Cauchy principal value of $I(0)$ is also 0 it follows that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2} dx}{x+z}=e^{-z^2} \pi \text{erfi(z)}.$$

Comment: Where is my mistake? (I suspect it is wrong to use the PV of $I(0)$; but if it is, how can I come up with a proper calculation of $C$?)

Comment: @Dumdi44: There is absolutely no mistake, you have done brilliantly! :-) I've just computed the original integral for two random values of the arguments, as well as by using your formulas, and they both yield the same numerical result.